# Is there an addon or method to find all objects that don't have a certain modifier (solidify)?

Tags: modifiers, add-on

It would be very useful. It really sucks to come across a weird looking object after you have already worked on the export and have to go back to Blender to fix one mistake. Sometimes you have to go back multiple times because you keep coming across them. It would be cool if I could just select all then solidify them. Anyone know what I could do other than to just make sure to solidify each object as I create them?

Comment: is a python script solution ok for u?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use this python script:

```
import bpy
  
for o in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    if o.type == 'MESH':
        for eachMod in o.modifiers:
            if eachMod.type == "SOLIDIFY":
                print(o.name)
                o.select_set(True)
```

it will select and print out the names of all objects which have solidify modifiers.

Comment: Or as a one liner 
`[o.select_set(o.type == 'MESH' and not [m for m in o.modifiers if m.type == 'SOLIDIFY']) for o in bpy.context.scene.objects]` :)

Comment: Very nice!!!!

Comment: @Gorgious [Ahem!](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length).. sorry, I seem to have a slight cough today... :)

Comment: @RobinBetts Yeah ! it's a self-centered running joke but I can clearly see how it's a bad idea to encourage people to use this kind of monstrosity ^^